# can you please tell me how to add has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

can you please tell me how to add has_many relationship once we have create model and we didn't specify any relation or reference while creating model ?please guide me i m stuck with the problem how i do migration after creating mode my models are one is for "page,rb" and other is "subject.rb"

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new migration to add the foreign key

   eg: `rails g migration AddSubjectIdToPages`
2. run the migration
3. edit the models, and add the relation.

Comment: you can specify that how we can add relation

Answer (score 1):

To add to `Santhosh`'s answer, you'll need the following:

```
#app/models/page.rb
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :subject
end

#app/models/subject.rb
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pages
end
```

You'll need to use the [following database setup](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) to allow this to happen:

[image]

Thus, to answer your question:

```
$ rails g migration AddSubjectIDToPages

#db/migrate/add_subject_id_to_pages______.rb
class AddSubjectIdtoPages < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      add_column :pages, :subject_id, :integer
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: i am also using this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for studies but i need more in detail because i m beginner in #ruby on #rails

Comment: yes i m tried to studying that and also understand topic completely but i m begginer so face alot of problems

Comment: Well you have StackOverflow to ask questions on -- if you have any further issues, you can just ask on here.

Comment: i have asked question on stack over flow as my question in mention in the above ask question

Comment: Have you followed the steps?